# Pass ArrayList of Arrays (e.g. ArrayList<String[]>) to Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

How do I pass an ArrayList of arrays to an intent in Android? I know you can pass an `ArrayList<String>`, but is it possible to pass an `ArrayList<String[]>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but you need to pass it as a `Serializable` and you'll need to cast the result when you extract the extra. Since `ArrayList` implements `Serializable` and `String[]` is inherently serializable, the code is straightforward. To pass it:

```
ArrayList<String[]> list = . . .;
Intent i = . . .;

i.putExtra("strings", list);
```

To retrieve it:

```
Intent i = . . .;
ArrayList<String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) getSerializableExtra("strings");
```

You'll have to suppress (or live with) the unchecked conversion warning.